# Find minimum value of $27^{\sin x}+81^{\cos x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find the minimum value of the expression

$$27^{\sin x}+81^{\cos x}$$

Comment: @IlmoEuro, when one is minimum $=-1,$ the other is $0$ ? How shall we guarantee that this will give us the required minimum value?

Comment: Maybe you can play around with the cos and sin terms using a formula to eliminate one of them.
$27^{\sin x} + 81^{\cos x} = 3^{2\sin x}\left( 1+ 3^{3\cos x - 2\sin x}\right)$

Answer (score 3):

A plot of the function shows that the minimum occurs at about $x=4$.  Of course, the function is periodic, so that same minimum occurs every $2\pi$. The derivative of the expression is 
$$\log (27) 27^{\sin (x)} \cos (x)-\log (81) \sin (x) 81^{\cos (x)},$$
where $\log$ is the natural logarithm.  The roots of the derivative cannot be expressed in elementary terms but Newton's method with an initial guess of $x_0=4$ can be used to find that root of the derivative (and, therefore, the minimum of your original expression) occurs at about 
$$x\approx 3.9925158.$$
Plugging this back into the original expression, we get that the minimum value is about 
$$0.139117.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard rule of differentiation:

1. Additivity $(f+g)'=f'+g'$
2. Chain rule $f(g(x))' =  f'(g(x))g'(x)$

together with $a^{g(x)}= e^{g(x)\ln a}$. Set it to zero...

> ...but it doesn't look like having nice solutions: Ask [Wolfram](http://tinyurl.com/lklrkbg)